# Is there a Mac OSX version of UbuntuOne planned for the near future?

Tags: ubuntu-one, mac, macosx

Since there is no UbuntuOne client for Mac OSX to download, will there be one in the near future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Canonical employee responded to that question on the Ubuntu One blog with

> [A Mac client is on our radar and something we hope to be able to deliver next year.](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/?p=1241#comment-1656)

in November of 2011. Of course the Ubuntu One client is open source, so anyone interested in helping to make this go faster should [contact the Ubuntu One team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuone).

Answer (score 6):

We have released a Mac OS X version as of today. You can find it here:

- https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/mac/

and check out the announcement here:

- http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/12/19/official-mac-os-x-client-for-ubuntu-one/

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on github that provides limited functionality

https://github.com/chrisledet/Ubuntu-One-Mac

EDIT:
as Oliviera points out, that link appears to be dead, though the folks over at omgUbuntu are telling us that there is a functional version out there for mac 
check this out.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/new-mac-app-brings-ubuntu-one-to-os-x

EDIT 2: If you are just looking to download/sync files down (not up yet) you can use this python script: https://github.com/ddimmich/unbuntuone-python - this is something I wrote to download music bought off the store.

Comment: The github project cited above gives me a 404 error. Is there a project still alive to port Ubuntu One Client to Mac OSX? I'd really love to use Ubuntu One as my main cloud service but it would be impossible till I can use it in all my devices at the same time... I would be glad to contribute if there is some project underway. Best, Aluizio.

Comment: @AluizioOliveira that github link shows as operational here...