# Will there be a Mac version of Ubuntu One?

Tags: mac, apple

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Mac OSX version of UbuntuOne planned for the near future?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85209/is-there-a-mac-osx-version-of-ubuntuone-planned-for-the-near-future)

Will there be a Mac version of Ubuntu One for syncing between desktop and other devices, or is it only through a browser?

Comment: This is not the best place to ask this question though

Comment: are you referring to ubuntu one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/85209/8724.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Ubuntu one team did post a job opening for a Mac software developer on their website. So it may come in the future.

Ubuntu one is already available on other operating systems such as Windows, Android, and iOS

Source Link
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/ubuntu-one-team-seeking-mac-dev/