# Ubuntu in macbook pro

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, 32-bit, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

I just got myself a macbook pro with a quad core processor. Apart from OSX Lion I would like to have Ubuntu on it as dual boot. I wondered if you could recommend me which Linux version I could choose, or either 32 or 64 bits?
On the other hand, does anybody know if it's possible to pair the Music/Videos/Downloads folder from both OS?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Alemanio

Comment: Hello, you should only ask one question per question. As for their solutions, look at the following links: [Difference between 32-bit and 64-bit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034), [Syncing folders with Ubuntu One](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85209), [Installing Ubuntu on Macbook Pro](http://askubuntu.com/questions/183215)

Answer (score 0):

Since Macbook pro has 4 GB of memory,it would be best to go with the 64bit version.

Of course you can dual boot both operating systems.You can take a look at this [OMG Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/dual-boot-os-ubuntu) article.

Ubuntu is a very straight-forward linux distro even for a rookie and you may see similar characteristics with Mac OSX.Alternatively,you can try [Pingy OS](http://pinguyos.com/) which is based on Ubuntu and aims to be more user friendly.