# How to install Ubuntu 12.04 on MacBook Pro?

Tags: installation, macbook-pro

How to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a MacBook Pro?

I just bought one and I want to install Ubuntu alongside Mac OS X. I have tried the same way as with Windows, but it seems the Mac cannot recognize the Ubuntu CD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you might have bought the latest MacBook Pro, which is the 10,1 model.  People are still investigating how to get Ubuntu working completely on that hardware, so I would not recommend installing Ubuntu on it unless you know what you're doing and want to make a serious time commitment.

Here's the link to the relevant Ubuntu help page:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro10-1/Precise  There's a link to the forum thread where people are working on the hardware issues.  There's also instructions on how to find out what model you have and a link to a directory of help pages for the older models.

Now to specifically answer your question...The general instructions for installing a dual-boot from the Ubuntu cd are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation).  It involves installing rEFIt.  I expect it will work for you, but as I said above, the real problem may be afterwards, when trying to get all the hardware to work.